# не удается компиляция файла в texstudio - русская версия

Tags: latex

простейший файл:

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hellow world!
\end{document}

кодировка utf8, имя директория и файла на английском
texstudio 4.2.5

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проверил - у меня все компилируется :-). Какой дистрибутив теха? (например, у миктеха могут быть проблемы с BOM у файла в UTF8; старый дистрибутив по умолчанию может не есть UTF8 без явного указания кодировки) Верно ли настроены пути к латеху в texstudio?

Comment: Напишите текст ошибки из лога - так хотя бы будет понятно, в каком направлении смотреть проблему.